# Which real functions benefit from the Fundamental Theorem of Interval Analysis?

Tags: computational-number-theory, applied-mathematics, theories-of-arithmetic

I'm reading Introduction to Interval Analysis, by Moore, Baker & Cloud and complementing it with Global Optimization using Interval Analysis, by Hansen & Walster.

Theorem 5.1 - Fundamental Theorem of Interval Analysis states that given a real function $f$, if $F$ is an inclusion isotonic interval extension of $f$, then
$f(X_1, X_2..) \subseteq F(X_1, X_2...)$

Later, they prove that natural extensions of real rational functions are always extensions and inclusive isotonic; therefore, we can apply the fundamental theorem.

However, in other literature and examples, they seem to apply this theorem to real (not rational) functions, such as $e^x$ or $\sqrt{x}$. I've struggled to find a justification. Can someone point me in the right direction? Is this applicable to all real functions? Maybe just the continuous ones?
Thanks in advance, and apologies for the subpar English.

Comment: If you want to see good answers to your post, it should be as self-contained as possible. In particular, in this case it should include the relevant definitions. Also, you should be quite specific. In this case, describe fully and in detail a specific case where the application of the theorem seems doubtful/unclear to you.